# NASA's Space Datasets

Tags: astronomy

I am looking for data on the spatial positions of planetary bodies, asteroids, stars, galaxies, etc. In doing that I was led to [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons) which requires you to use telnet to command-line step through querying for data! I was hoping there would be an FTP or CSV somewhere but haven't found anything.

That got me here to ask about what major data sets NASA offers. I'm sure they have hundreds or thousands of small data sets, updates, and variations of collections of such, but I'm not looking for a list of all that. I just would like to know what (and where) the major data sets are.

From my understanding so far, there are:

1. [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons). (I am not sure if [this FTP](ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub//eph/planets/ascii/) is the same dataset, which would be great). I think this includes all planets, including Jupiter and whatnot, which the "Geosciences" data below doesn't (maybe because Jupiter is a gas planet instead of rock).

   > highly accurate ephemerides for solar system objects ( 789751 asteroids, 3542 comets, 190 planetary satellites, 8 planets, the Sun, L1, L2, select spacecraft, and system barycenters ).
2. [Lunar Data FTP](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/Lunar/) (and [description](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/dataserv/moon.html)). I think this is just a map of the surface of the moon using LiDAR.
3. [Other Planet Geoscience Data FTP](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/dataserv/holdings.html). I think this is mainly for Mars, Venus, Mercury, Moon, Earth, and Asteroids. (Doesn't mention planets like Jupiter and whatnot).
4. [ATMOS data](https://remus.jpl.nasa.gov/atmos/atftp.html) (and [FTP](ftp://thunder.jpl.nasa.gov/atmos)). "Atmospheric Trace Molecule Spectroscopy". Not really sure what this is.
5. [data](https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataaccess#DRIVE) (and [FTP](ftp://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/)). ["Physical Oceanography Distributed Active Archive Center (PO.DAAC)"](https://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/AboutPodaac).
6. https://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/data/access/
7. https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/about/ftp.php
8. https://earthdata.nasa.gov/earth-observation-data/near-real-time/download-nrt-data
9. https://pmm.nasa.gov/data-access/downloads
10. https://cdaweb.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdawlib/0MASTERS/
11. ftp://ftp.nnvl.noaa.gov/
12. https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/db-perl/W3Browse/w3table.pl?tablehead=name%3Dugc&Action=More+Options
13. ftp://legacy.gsfc.nasa.gov/
14. ... Not really sure what else. I know there are the images available, but mainly looking for the data.

I am specifically wondering if there is any data on the [positions of the galaxies](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13536/3d-shapefile-or-pointcloud-data-for-stars-galaxies-in-observable-universe), but not sure if NASA has that (would be helpful to know if they do or don't).

Comment: can I suggest that you post everything from *"From my understanding so far, there are:"* on as a self-answer (and even consider setting it to a "community-wiki")?